# Custom Exception Handling in ASP.NET webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, exception, wsdl

I developed a asp.net 2.0 web service (.asmx), now my client said that

> "there is no fault exception available. It contains only request and
>   response. We need to handle the exception scenarios while we are
>   calling the webservice, Could you please update the WSDL on fault
>   exception and send back the updated WSDL to us to proceed with the
>   Client stubs.
>
> Webservice Response should have the below mentioned error code for the
>   failure cases from the webservice as mentioned below :
>
> ```
>             Error code:  Error Information
>              002           Server Down
>              003       Invalid Input Format
> ```

etc. 
I am not sure how can i update my code so that the "fault exception" tags are generated in asmx wsdl file & how should i throw such exception. 
Any help/suggestion please or please let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Id love to see a server thats down respond with `Server Down`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, ASP.NET web services (asmx) does not support custom soap faults. On a different note, it's [considered as legacy technology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx) (by Microsoft) - there is no point in developing new services in it.

Use WCF services (that are more flexible in all manners) - see [this simple tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) to get started with WCF.

Coming to your question, WCF support custom soap fault (known as fault contract in WCF lingo) - see [this simple tutorial](http://wcftutorial.net/Fault-Contract.aspx) for adding fault contract to a WCF service.

Comment: unfortunately client server supports .net 2.0 only, that's why i have to use  asmx.

Comment: @SaQiB, only suggestion that I have is that perhaps you should attempt to educate and convince your client to upgrade from .NET 2.0 (mainstream support ended in Apr 2011). Further, run-time version for .NET 3.0 & 3.5 both remains same at 2.0 - so upgrading is a quite risk-free. Essentially, there are only bug-fixes to core libraries in 3.5 and unless your code exploits those bugs, you will be safe!

Comment: +1 for your comment. yes i've already communicated to client that upgrade is necessary :-), till the i have started development of this web service in wcf. i'll get back if i encounter any problem in this solution

Answer (score 1):

You should add [FaultContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx) attributes with exception information to your method heads

Comment: thank, it helped a bit but looks like this is in .net framework 4.0 not 2.0? am i right.

Comment: but i need the solution in 2.0 :-(

Comment: try this  than ;) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETExceptionHandling.aspx